# What is the meaning of "UPDATE table SET column1 = value AND column2 value WHERE condition" in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

If the "," in an `UPDATE` statement is replaced with `AND`, what the meaning in SQL?

Normal Update Statement :

```
UPDATE table 
SET column1 = value , 
    column2 = value 
WHERE condition
```

My question statement :

```
UPDATE table 
SET column1 = value AND column2 = value 
WHERE condition
```

The affected rows seem to be different, so I want to know what my question statement mean in SQL?

[Original test Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkFri.png)

After inserting query(from original)  : Update testing set column1 = 2 , column2 =5

[Normal Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n61sR.png)

After inserting query(from original) : Update testing set column1 = 2 AND column2 =5

[My Question Statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0EuP.png)

if I insert the query(from original) :Update testing set column1 = 2 AND  =4

[the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGAcN.png)

Comment: Doesn't look like ANSI SQL so which DBMS are you using?

Comment: _"The affected rows seem to be different"_  how **exactly** are they different?

Comment: @Phil How can I know what DBMS I am using? The affected rows in the normal statement is more then the my question statement.

Comment: What software are you running your queries on?

Comment: @Phil I am using phpMyadmin, should be MySql?

Comment: Right, so your DBMS is [tag:mysql]. When asking questions about databases, please remember to include the appropriate tag

Comment: Why not conduct an experiment?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html), the _assignment list_ should only be made of `col_name = value [, col_name = value ]...`. All I can think of is that it is being evaluated as a boolean expression, eg `column1 = ( value AND column2 = value )` where `column2 = value` may be a comparison. If you could show how the results are different, I'm sure that would help explain the difference

Comment: @Phil ya, I think you are correct. it is evaluated as boolean expression....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably wrong to write `2 AND b = 1` though some databases evaluate it and others don't

If your intention is to set multiple columns in one go, you MUST use a comma

If you use this construct, perhaps some databases will process it according to bitwise-logical operation or they will treat any non zero value as true/false and any zero as false/true, and others will process it according to Boolean-logical operation

In the example strawberry kindly posted: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3KawkrD8QfjJu6YyfuzB7U/0

Set the db to MySQL and run it; it works out - MySQL is probably treating 2 as true, so the operation becomes:

```
SET c = true and true --when b = 1
SET c = true and false --when b=0
```

You can see your c column is set to 1 or 0 depending on the truth

```
SET c = (2 AND (b = 1)) 
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        This whole thing is turned into a value. 
        for C, it does NOT set column B at all
```

Now change the DB to Postgres and run it again

This time you get an error that AND expects Boolean operands, and the integer 2 is not acceptable

Hence in Postgres while this might be acceptable:

```
SET d = (c=1 AND b=2) --sets a true or false value for d
```

Your other form is not acceptable

--

Long story short, you probably intended to set multiple columns: use a comma.

Comment: You have true and false, but you also need false and true for completeness

Answer (score 1):

We can see from this simple experiment...

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3KawkrD8QfjJu6YyfuzB7U/0

...that ...

```
UPDATE my_table SET c = 2 AND b = 1;
```

... is interpreted as...

```
UPDATE my_table SET c ........ = 1;
```